# PLSQL extract singles value

Tags: sql, oracle, url-parsing

I want extract single values from links:

```
    Column1                                            
    ---------------
   <a href=" https://link; m=date1>Link</a>  
   <a href=" https://link; m=date2>Link</a>
```

The resultant column should look like:

```
    Column1                                    Column2   
    ---------------
   <a href=" https://link; m=date1>Link</a>     date1 
   <a href=" https://link; m=date2>Link</a>     date2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
insert into B_TEST_TABLE values('<a href=" https://link; m=date1>Link</a>');
insert into B_TEST_TABLE values('<a href=" https://link; m=date2>Link</a>');

select COLUMN1, 
substr(COLUMN1, instr(COLUMN1, 'm=') +2 , instr(COLUMN1, '>') - (instr(COLUMN1, 'm=') + 2)) 
from B_TEST_TABLE;
```

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. You should try to explain what you did and why this answer is corect instead of just posting code. This way you help others understand why does this code might be the most appropriate and in which situation.

Answer (score 0):

Try `regexp_substr` as following:

```
SQL> SELECT
  2      REGEXP_SUBSTR('<a href=" https://link; m=date1>Link</a>', 'm=(.*?)>', 1, 1, NULL, 1)
  3  FROM
  4      DUAL;

REGEX
-----
date1

SQL>
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the exact sample data given with one target `"m=<value wanted>"` pattern per line, you can use this REGEXP_REPLACE() example:

```
with tbl(id, str) as (
  select 1, '<a href=" https://link; m=date1>Link</a>' from dual union all  
  select 2, '<a href=" https://link; m=date2>Link</a>' from dual union all
  select 3, '<a href=" https://link; m=>Link</a>' from dual union all
  select 4, NULL from dual
)
select id, regexp_replace(str, '.*m=(\w+).*', '\1') col1
from tbl;
```

Match `"m="` anywhere in the line and save one or more word characters that follows into a remembered group.  Return the first remembered group.  Note if the pattern is not found the input string will be returned.  You could make it return a NULL (in the case of line 3) by making the group match zero or more word characters: `'.*m=(\w*).*'`.  Think carefully about what you want returned if a match is not found.